# ImproperlyConfigured MySQL in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': 'my.cnf',
        },
    }
}
```

my.cnf:

```
[client]
database=fake
host=127.0.0.1
port=3306
user=fake
password=fake
default-character-set=utf8
```

These files are in the same directory of my Django project. (The actual `my.cnf` has real credentials). I have [installed mysqlclient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42451292/3704831). However, when I try to `runserver` I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 299, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 116, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

What configuration step(s) have I missed or farked up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363522/django-dev-server-error-image-not-found) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593087/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-error-loading-mysqldb-module)

It looks like the library is not where it should be. From your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451212/trouble-installing-mysqlclient-via-pip/42451292#42451292) it looks like you installed it at

> /usr/local/mysql/

but Django is expecting it to be at `/usr/lib/`

Creating the symlinks like in the other questions should fix this for you:

> sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
>
> sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I still have a few more hurdles to cross, but this answer got me past THAT error message.